# Parsing "html_attributions" from Google Places response in JAVA

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

Per policy it is mandatory show "html_attributions" in the app. This response is received as - 
"html_attributions" : [      "Listings by \u003ca href=\"http:// Some website.com/\"\u003esSome website\u003c/a\u003e"   ]

When I parse it as jObject.getJSONArray("html_attributions") I get - 
`["Listings by <a href=\"http:\/\/www.some website.com\/\">some website<\/a>"]`

This cannot be displayed as is since it is not html correct. Is there any method to parse this attribution correctly so that html valid string is extracted?

Comment: have you found solution? I suggest it is in xml format so parse that html_attributions in xml parsing. which will give you link for that

Answer (score 1):

Go through this Google Places Api [Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/blob/master/PlaceComplete/Application/src/main/java/com/example/google/playservices/placecomplete/MainActivity.java) which describes a way of doing so.

It has a method `formatPlaceDetails` that Format details of the place for display. It does not support HTML tags directly, they need to be encoded first.

```
private static Spanned formatPlaceDetails(Resources res, CharSequence name, String id,
            CharSequence address, CharSequence phoneNumber, Uri websiteUri) {
        Log.e(TAG, res.getString(R.string.place_details, name, id, address, phoneNumber,
                websiteUri));
        return Html.fromHtml(res.getString(R.string.place_details, name, id, address, phoneNumber,
                websiteUri));

    }
```

**string.xml**

```
<string name="place_details">&lt;b&gt;%1$s&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;i&gt;Place Id: %2$s&lt;/i&gt;&lt;br/&gt;Address: %3$s&lt;br/&gt;Phone: %4$s&lt;br/&gt;Website: %5$s</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may help

From google I have found this [on this page](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search?hl=en). Which is html tag and if we want exact url than we have to get from that html string parsed from xml.

```
 This is an example of an attribution in JSON format:

"html_attributions" : [
      "Listings by \u003ca href=\"http://www.example.com/\"\u003eExample Company\u003c/a\u003e"
],

This is an attribution in XML format:
<html_attribution>Listings by <a href="http://www.example.com/">Example Company</a></html_attribution>
```